# Python: Is there a way to subtract date time objects with the values written as "hours":"minutes":"seconds":"milliseconds"

Tags: python, datetime, format, difference

I'm trying to convert strings into a date time object given the hours minutes seconds and milliseconds, so I can find the difference in time between the two strings. If there is a better way to do this please let me know, that'd be great.

the format of the date time object looks like this:

But when I tried subtracting two strings converted into date time objects the result wasn't correct. for example:

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%H:%M:%S:%f'

x = '12:51:11:153'
time1 = datetime.strptime(x, format)


y = '13:51:11:153'
time2 = datetime.strptime(y, format)

difference = time2 - time1

print(difference)

"The print" = 0:00:00
```

Am I missing something for the format, or is there a special method to subtract datetime objects from each other? Also, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  I get output of `1:00:00` when I run this code.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to *format* the timedelta to string?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is right. I can't reproduce that. This is my code and the output if I run it.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
format = '%H:%M:%S:%f'
time1 = datetime.strptime("12:51:11:153", format)
time2 = datetime.strptime("13:51:11:153", format)

print((time2-time1).total_seconds())
```

***--> 3600.0 seconds*** (type is float)

**type(time2-time1)** --> <class 'datetime.timedelta'>
**time2-time1** --> datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)